# What does Qur'an 75:4 mean by using an example of fingertips?

Tags: tafseer, surat-al-qiyamah

I was going through the translation of Surah Al Qiyamah and I came across the expression in [verses 3-4](http://quran.com/75/3-4) which reads,

> 3. Does man (a disbeliever) think that We shall not assemble his bones?
> 4. Yes, We are Able to put together in perfect order **the tips of his fingers.**

This made me wonder, why is the expression of putting together fingertips used? There could be other expressions too, so what is unique about this?

Please reply with your views and tafseer so that we get an entire view of this verse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially what I thought it could relate to, was that fingers were numerous and tips could refer to small surface areas which could eventually point out that Allah will return back the slightest of details . This is true but a Jummah Sermon in my local masjid By Sheikh Abdul Ghaffar Salafi , just helped understand it better.

The **"finger-tips"** expression used here is to denote the **"Finger-Prints"** . If we recall , no two people have the same fingerprints even though they might look alike in all aspects . This seems to explain the uniqueness of the verse with regards to the resurrection . Allah says that He will(capable /able to) return the same fingerprints to us that we have in this world.

So with respect to those disbelievers who claimed that they will be gone forever , this verse brings up the Resurrection issue in the best possible argument . There could be more to it though which I'm yet to understand.

Comment: Finger prints was probably used at the time as signature (although I have no evidence). The word used here is fingertips not finger prints. Not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Finger prints would become a bit scientific and Allah has used expressions that could be understood by people about 1400 years ago. Even if they were used as signature,they would imply the same thing that each person's fingerprint is unique..

Comment: I agree with you that finger prints is a good context. What I am not sure about it, does finger tips mean finger prints? Aren't there specific words for finger prints in Arabic? I am not sure about that part.

Comment: Finger-tips would imply everything upto the tips, and recreating the tip of the finger would mean getting the exact copy of features on it(including finger-prints) .

Answer (score -1):

Just because nobody brought this up yet:

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/the-filter/11424695/Polite-promiscuous...-gay-What-does-your-ring-finger-say-about-you.html

It appears the length of your fingers is indicative of character & biological traits.  When I read this article, I immediately remembered the Quran's reference.

Answer (score -1):

Quran is book of signs ,not book of science...look at the signs..in Surah An-Nisa [4:56] signs of pain receptors in skin are shown,we shouldnt expect Quran speaking about dermis and epidermis.